# counting number of words in linux

Tags: linux, count

I have a file with lines that have the format: 1,4,2,3,2 etc.
I want to count the number of elements (numbers) in this line. I tried using the wc command, but wc -L seems to count all the elements in my line (including commas) and wc returns the number of lines. How can I get the result I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get a count of numbers (i.e. "words") for a single line:

```
echo '1, 2, 3, 4, 5' | wc -w
```

This will output `5`.

If you want to get a count for every line in a given file, you can do it in a `while` loop:

```
while read line; do echo $line | wc -w; done < your_file
```

This will output a count for each line in the file on a new line (so, the first output line corresponds to the first line in your file, etc.).

If your lines do not contain spaces and are directly comma-delimited, such as `1,2,3,4,5`, you can use `tr` to replace the commas with spaces to have the "word count" function the same way:

```
echo '1,2,3,4,5' | tr ',' ' ' | wc -w
```

or

```
while read line; do echo $line | tr ',' ' ' | wc -w; done < your_file
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `wc -w` to count words. There is also -c for bytes, -l for lines, -m for characters. -L is for the lenght of the longest line.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `,` before counting the numbers:

```
cat file | tr -d ',' | wc -c
```

(`wc -c` counts the number of characters in a file / stream.)

However this will work only if the numbers are all single numbers. If not, I would use `awk`:

```
awk -FS',' '{c+=NF}END{print c}' file
```